# Django best practice for scripts organizing

Tags: django

I had the project on Django 3.1 with the following layout:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── asgi.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── wsgi.py
│   ├── core
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── fixtures
│   │   │   ├── Client.json
│   │   │   └── DataFeed.json
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── migrations
│   │   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   │   ├── 0002_auto_20201009_0950.py
│   │   │   └── __init__.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   └── tests
│   │       └── __init__.py
│   └── manage.py
```

I want to add 2 scripts to this project:

- *download_xml.py* - to check and download .xml files from external sources by schedule (every ~30 min)
- *update_db_info.py* - to be invoked by *download_xml.py*  and transfer data from downloaded xml to the database

**What is the best django practice for organizing a placement for this kind of scripts?**

**My ideas**:

1. just create *scripts* folder inside of an **app/core** and put scripts there. Invoke them using *cron*
2. run `python manage.py startapp db_update`
   so the new app in django will be created. I will remove migrations, views, models etc from it and put scripts there. use *cron* again
3. Create **app/core/management/commands** folder and put scripts there. Call them by cron using `python manage.py download_xml &&  python manage.py download_xml update_db_info`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 3 (mostly)

However if `download_xml.py` doesn't use or rely on Django, I would put it in a `scripts` directory outside of the Django project (but still in source control).  You might decide not to do this if the script does need to be deployed with your app.  It doesn't need to be a management command though.

`update_db_info.py` definitely sounds like it would be best suited as a management command.